# Qual a diferença entre MER (Modelo de Entidade Relacionamento) e DER (Diagrama de Entidade Relacionamento)?

Tags: sql, modelagem, modelo-relacional, diagrama, der

Qual a diferença entre um diagrama do MER e um do DER, com exemplos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O MER é o que você quer fazer efetivamente, é a ferramenta para criar modelos de dados e seus relacionamentos, em geral que depois será produzido em um banco de dados relacional. O DER é só uma maneira visual de montar e analisar este modelo.

O MER é abstrato, é só um conceito, podemos dizer que ele só existe no pensamento, embora você possa colocá-lo no papel de forma desorganizada. O DER é algo com regras próprias de como desenhar esse modelo que representará a organização de dados que usará no banco de dados, então podemos dizer que ele é um pouco mais concreto, até por ser visível e passível de transferência entre pessoas e até ferramentas na comunicação do que será (ou foi) feito. Claro, ele ainda é uma abstração.

Só dá para apresentar o DER, só ele é visual. O MER dá para explicar, mas no momento que for montar um exemplo de forma organizada e visual está fazendo um DER. Se já viu um diagrama já tem um exemplo.

Existem várias notações diferentes para um DER. Uma delas pegando da Wikipedia:

[image: DER]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

O MER (Modelo Entidade-Relacionamento) é uma linguagem que possui o objetivo de descrever modelos conceituais de banco de dados. Foi proposta por Peter Chen em 1976.
Por meio dela é possível representar conceitos como entidades e relacionamentos. Segue parte da notação (ou alfabeto) da linguagem MER.

[image: Notação Peter Chen] [Fonte](https://sites.google.com/site/uniplibancodedados1/aulas/aula-4---modelo-entidade-e-relacionamentos)

Assim como existem diversos idiomas (ou línguas) no mundo (como a Língua Portuguesa ou a Japonesa), sabemos que, embora diferentes (alfabeto, sintaxe, semântica, etc), todas apresentam o mesmo objetivo de permitir a comunicação entre as pessoas.

Sendo assim, da mesma forma que existe a linguagem MER para descrição de modelos conceituais, existem outras linguagens que permitem atingir o mesmo objetivo.

Após a proposta de Peter Chen (lá em 1976), surgiram outras propostas de linguagens com alfabetos (ou notações) diferentes. Uma muito famosa é a do James Martin (também conhecida como a notação pé de galinha), exemplificada a seguir. No caso, a principal diferença entre elas seria o alfabeto, mantendo os conceitos do MER (entidades, relacionamentos, atributos, etc).

[image: Notação James Martin] [Fonte](https://sites.google.com/site/uniplibancodedados1/aulas/aula-4---modelo-entidade-e-relacionamentos)

É por meio das linguagens de modelagem que podemos criar os Diagramas Entidade-Relacionamento (modelos conceituais) de nossos projetos de banco de dados. Seguem exemplos de Diagramas Entidade-Relacionamento em cada notação (Peter Chen e James Martin, respectivamente):

[image: DER na Notação Peter Chen] [Fonte](https://www.ime.usp.br/~andrers/aulas/bd2005-1/aula6.html)

[image: DER na Notação James Martin] [Fonte](https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/pt/o-que-e-diagrama-entidade-relacionamento)

Resumindo:

1. MER: linguagem que permite descrever modelos conceituais de banco de
   dados na notação de Peter Chen;
2. DER: modelo criado por meio de uma linguagem de modelagem, que utiliza os conceitos presentes no MER (como entidade e relacionamento), podendo utilizar notações diferentes.